# Best practice for multithreaded applications that talk to a sql database

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, connection

I have 20 factory machines all processing tasks. I have a database adapter that talks to a MYSQL database that the machines store all their info in. Is it safe to have each factory machine panel have it's own database adapter and updater thread? The updater thread just continuously checks to see if the panel's current taskID is the same as the current in the database and if not it repopulates the panel with information about the new task.

I'm not certain if having too many connections will add overhead or not?

Comment: I don't think 20 connections will kill the MySQL server :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than having many connection all doing same task create one process which maintains the list of taskid (if it is different for all machines) and checks the current taskid in database. if it is changed then send message to all the machines (which has change in their taskid)to update their panels. This will avoid unnecessary load on database and will also handle increase in number of machines without any impact.

Comment: Upon trying to implement previous things I believe this to be how I am going to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

RDBS are designed to be accessed by multiple clients at a given time. It's one of their purpose.

So I don't think 20, or even a thousand of simultaneous connection will cause any problem at all.

Comment: +1 I agree; that's what RDBMSs are designed for. However, normally a connection requires certain resources on the server (e.g. memory) so you'd have to consider that if you really wanted thousands (or millions) of simultaneous connections.

Answer (score 1):

The number of connection in mysql is controlled by `max_connections` (total number of allowed simultaneous connection) system variable and `max_user_connections`(max number of simultaneous connections per user). Take a look on your server settings and maybe change them. Default numbers are definitely bigger than 20 though.